# Help managing partitions for installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I want to dual boot Ubuntu along with Windows 10, running in Legacy boot.
I already have 4 partitions(MBR, and I know creating a 5th one isn't allowed) [partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zHuK.png)
and have the following volumes
[volumes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbsXo.png)
I want to create 3 drives using the unallocated space, 2 both accessible by both windows and linux and the 3rd for installing ubuntu.

I suspect that partition 3 is C drive(how do I check?) and partition 4 has the D drive and unallocated space. I have no problem formatting D drive if it helps.

Any help for making a partition for Ubuntu will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First three partitions are primary partitions and fourth is a secondary partition and when you create a fifth one its a extended volume.

First you unmount the partitioning and then try the command you can use is lsblk.

sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

to check which drives your system can see:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```